# Dataset query for keys of upper levels

Tags: dataset, associations

Say I have a Dataset like this:

```
dat=Dataset[<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>]
```

I want to get the keys of upper levels as elements in the lower levels, say something like this:

```
datNeed=Dataset[<|"a" -> {2, "a"}, "b" -> {"y", "b"}, "c" -> {{2, 3}, "c"}|>]
```

To get `datNeed`, what query should be performed over `dat`?

I know `KeyValueMap` may get something similar but the caveat is that keys will be dropped, which I hope not.

Comment: `KeyValueMap[#->{#2,#}&]@dat`?

Comment: Thanks, @kglr . But it will drop the keys as well.

Comment: `Association@@(KeyValueMap[#->{#2,#}&]@dat)`?

Comment: Thanks @kglr! This works. I was thinking there might be some ascending operations using the `Query` hack to resolve this. Now it seems not easy to achieve it in the `Query` way.

Comment: @sunt05, I think your last key-value should be `"c"->{{2, 3}, "c"}`

Comment: thanks @alancalvitti, corrected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1, 1]]} &, dat] // Normal

(* <|"a" -> {2, "a"}, "b" -> {"y", "b"}, "c" -> {{2, 3}, "c"}|> *)
```

Comment: Excellent hack by using `MapIndexed`! Then it seems this one may elegantly fit into the `Query` form: `dat[MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1, 1]]} &]]`

Answer (score 10):

```
Association @@ (KeyValueMap[# -> {#2, #}&] @ dat) // Normal
```

> <|"a" -> {2, "a"}, "b" -> {"y", "b"}, "c" -> {{2, 3}, "c"}|>

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is:

```
dat[{Keys, {Values,Keys} /* Thread} /* Apply[AssociationThread]] //Normal
```

> <|"a" -> {2, "a"}, "b" -> {"y", "b"}, "c" -> {{2, 3}, "c"}|>

Answer (score 4):

I have a set of related functions that I use extensively in data work including `keyValueMap`, which is an operator that lets you pass user defined functions to apply to `Keys`, `Values` or both.

apply `g` to `Values`:

```
keyValueMap[Key -> g_][as_Association] := 
   AssociationThread[
    KeyValueMap[List /* First][as] -> KeyValueMap[g][as]]
```

apply `f` to `Keys`:

```
keyValueMap[f_ -> Value][as_Association] := 
   AssociationThread[
    KeyValueMap[f][as] -> KeyValueMap[List /* Last][as]]
```

Apple `f` to `Keys`, `g` to `Values`:

```
keyValueMap[f_ -> g_][as_Association] := 
   AssociationThread[KeyValueMap[f][as] -> KeyValueMap[g][as]]
```

Here `Key` and `Value` are just symbolic placeholders, slightly more mnemonic than using `Identity`, (can `Blank` be used instead?)

In your application, use:

```
dat[keyValueMap[Key -> List /* Reverse]]  (* Normal *)
```

> <|"a" -> {2, "a"}, "b" -> {"y", "b"}, "c" -> {{2, 3}, "c"}|>

or simply `List` if order is not important.

To motivate the discussion, additional operators can be defined using `keyValueMap` above. For example `keySubKeyMap` with the following application:

Suppose the `Values` are themselves nested `Associations`. How to `Map` a function combining upper level `Keys` with those at lower level (hence `Sub`)?

```
dat2 = Dataset[<|"a" -> <|2 -> 10|>, "b" -> <|"y" -> 11, "z" -> 12|>, 
   "c" -> <|2 -> 13, 3 -> 14|>|>]
```

Use:

```
keySubKeyMap[f_] := 
 keyValueMap[
  Key -> List /* Replace[{k_, as_} :> KeyMap[Curry[f, 2][k]][as]]]
```

Then:

```
dat2[keySubKeyMap[f]] // Normal
```

> <|"a" -> <|f["a", 2] -> 10|>, 
>    "b" -> <|f["b", "y"] -> 11, f["b", "z"] -> 12|>, 
>    "c" -> <|f["c", 2] -> 13, f["c", 3] -> 14|>|>

Answer (score 0):

```
 GroupBy[Normal @ Normal @ dat, First, First @* MapApply[Reverse @* List]]
```

<|"a" -> {2, "a"}, "b" -> {"y", "b"}, "c" -> {{2, 3}, "c"}|>